# Access to Nifi flow using Nipy Api and LDAP

Tags: apache-nifi, nipyapi

I'm trying to obtain access to nifi flow project, through nipyapi and LDAP.
I have nify flow and registry up and running, and login/password('login'/'password')

```
import nipyapi
nipyapi.config.nifi_config.host = 'https://nifiexample.com/nifi'
nipyapi.config.registry_config.host = 'https://nifiexample.com/nifi-registry'
print(nipyapi.canvas.get_root_pg_id())
```

I read docs and found this method

```
nipyapi.security.set_service_ssl_context(service='nifi', ca_file=None, client_cert_file=None, client_key_file=None, client_key_password=None)
```

but as far as I'm not a developer I don't understand how to use it properly.
Can please someone tell me, what else configs/proprieties should I add to run this simple script?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Secured Connection Demo](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nipyapi-docs/nipyapi.demo.html#secured-connection) from the docs. The [Python code](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi/blob/master/nipyapi/demo/secure_connection.py) goes through this process step-by-step.

Understanding how NiFi uses [TLS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#security_configuration) and performs [authentication](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#user_authentication) and [authorization](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#multi-tenant-authorization) will also help these steps make sense.